# Edit file after No startup - Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot

I have made some editing in a file and now Lubuntu just shows the logo and the five dots.

I pressed ALT F2 and now I'm "in" somewhere, I believe it must be the "terminal".

I can locate the file `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf`

I edited what I THOUGHT was a spelling error - I thought [Seatdefaults] should be [Setdefaults] and I added this line:

```
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

and now the computer will not re-boot correctly.

How can I edit the file from where I am right now? (ALT F2 after failed boot)

Comment: post the output of `cat /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on  tty, then follow this,

```
sudo nano /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
```

Remove the below line and then save the file,

```
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```